# No connection established Error in firebase firestore & grpc

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It is a function to add new data if it does not exist by referring to existing data and update data if it exists. It works well, but after an hour `gRpc` error occurs. Details below:

`Error: No connection established
        at Http2CallStream.<anonymous> (D:\zyleTcpServer\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:68:41)
        at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:215:7)
        at D:\zyleTcpServer\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:75:22
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
    ---------------------------------------------
        at BunWrapper.Readable.on (D:\zyleTcpServer\node_modules\bun\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:729:33)
        at D:\zyleTcpServer\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:920:26
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Firestore._initializeStream (D:\zyleTcpServer\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:881:16)
        at D:\zyleTcpServer\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:1017:28 {
      code: 14,
      details: 'No connection established',
      metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
    }`

And here is my code

```js
<code>
    const docName = `${vin}-${dtc}`; //make doc
    const ebsRef = db.collection('events').doc(docName);
    await db.runTransaction((t) => t.get(ebsRef)
      .then(async (doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          return t.set({
           startDatetime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
           endDatetime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
           description: dtcData.description,
           dtcCode: dtc,
           eventType: brokenType,
           scannerCode: dtcData.scanner,
           vin,
          });
       }
       return t.update(ebsRef, {
         status: (rawDtc.status === '08' ? 2 : 1),
         endDatetime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
    </code>
    <br>
```

Is there a problem with my source code?
    How can i fix it..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Other **people reported to be having the same issue in the past week**, as mentioned on **[Firebase Functions Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/568)**. **This occurs to every kind of function that involves firestore and it's related to firestore changing `grpc` to `grpc-js`**. As mentioned in the conversation thread, there are some workarounds that you can try:

### Workaround

> **1 - Updating from "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0" to "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"**

OR

> **2 - Deleting your `/src/functions/node_modules` and `/src/functions/package-lock.json`, updating your dependencies, and pushing your changes that include your new dependencies in your `/src/functions/package.json` to your firebase app.**

---

At the end, your dependency should read:

`@grpc/grpc-js": "0.6.9"`

**This conversation thread [grpc/grpc-node#1027](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1027) also explain ways to update your deps and can also be of great help.**

Comment: I solved it through update firebase-admin to latest version. Thanks for your help!