# Firestore: GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x48b21b62 error. Code: 13 Message: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2

Tags: firebase

I get this error with the Firebase emulator when I try to insert a document. I'm a newbie in Firebase, so it might be I'm doing something stupid, but I can't figure it out.

**Note:** I took the code examples from [the doc for the web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en#web-version-9_6) version 9, as the [code for node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en#node.js_6) tells me there's no collection function in db. So I followed the advice in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/vp8ugv/error_dbcollection_is_not_a_function/)

Here are my Firebase dependencies :

```
zied@zied-N752VX:~/Work/WS/linkedinCv-back$ pnpm view firebase dependencies
{
  '@firebase/app': '0.9.7',
  '@firebase/app-compat': '0.2.7',
  '@firebase/app-types': '0.9.0',
  '@firebase/auth': '0.22.0',
  '@firebase/auth-compat': '0.3.7',
  '@firebase/database': '0.14.4',
  '@firebase/database-compat': '0.3.4',
  '@firebase/firestore': '3.10.0',
  '@firebase/firestore-compat': '0.3.6',
  '@firebase/functions': '0.9.4',
  '@firebase/functions-compat': '0.3.4',
  '@firebase/installations': '0.6.4',
  '@firebase/installations-compat': '0.2.4',
  '@firebase/messaging': '0.12.4',
  '@firebase/messaging-compat': '0.2.4',
  '@firebase/storage': '0.11.2',
  '@firebase/storage-compat': '0.3.2',
  '@firebase/performance': '0.6.4',
  '@firebase/performance-compat': '0.2.4',
  '@firebase/remote-config': '0.4.4',
  '@firebase/remote-config-compat': '0.2.4',
  '@firebase/analytics': '0.9.5',
  '@firebase/analytics-compat': '0.2.5',
  '@firebase/app-check': '0.6.4',
  '@firebase/app-check-compat': '0.3.4',
  '@firebase/util': '1.9.3'
}
```

My initialization code is the following

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";

// firebaseApps previously initialized using initializeApp()
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXX",
    authDomain: "linkedincv-bdbec.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "linkedincv-bdbec",
    storageBucket: "linkedincv-bdbec.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "472466845815",
    appId: "XXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXX",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const db = getFirestore(app);

const db = getFirestore(app);
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 4000);

export {db}
```

The code that triggers the error is the following:

```
import {db} from '../../../lib/middleware/firebaseInit'
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

export async function POST({request}) {
    try {
        const payload = await request.json();
        const uniqueUrl = payload.uniqueUrl;

        // Store the 'uniqueUrl' field in Firestore
        const docRef = await setDoc(doc(db, "json_cv", "testId"), payload)
        // Return the document ID of the stored object
        return {
            body: JSON.stringify({ documentId: docRef.id }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            status: 200
        };
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur during processing
        console.error(error);
        return {
            body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Failed to store unique URL' }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            status: 500
        };
    }
}
```

I saw some people [updated firebase-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551487/no-connection-established-error-in-firebase-firestore-grpc/58554698#58554698) to get it to work, but it seems this doesn't apply for me as I'm already at version 9.

Here's the error I receive:

```
[2023-04-13T06:09:01.286Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.19.1): GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x48b21b62 error. Code: 13 Message: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to this is in the other [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76003566/expected-type-firestore1-but-it-was-a-custom-firestore-object/76003901#76003901)

Long story short: when running in node.js, we have to use the library from `"firebase-admin"` and not from `"firebase"`

Also, the emulator is not initialized, only an environment variable has to be set before initializing firebase.