# Expected type 'Firestore$1', but it was: a custom Firestore object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It's my first project in firebase, I'm trying to insert a document (through the emulator), **from a Node.js app** and I get the error:

```
Expected type 'Firestore$1', but it was: a custom Firestore object
```

This is how I initialize firebase:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXX",
    authDomain: "linkedincv-bdbec.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "linkedincv-bdbec",
    storageBucket: "linkedincv-bdbec.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "472466845815",
    appId: "XXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXX",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = admin.firestore();
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 4000);

export {db}
```

My execution code is as follows:

```
import {db} from '../../../lib/middleware/firebaseInit'

export async function POST({request}) {
    try {
        const payload = await request.json();
        const uniqueUrl = payload.uniqueUrl;

        // const docRef = await setDoc(doc(db, "json_cv", "zied"), payload)
        const docRef = await db.collection("json_cv").doc("zied").set( payload)
        // Return the document ID of the stored object
        return {
            body: JSON.stringify({ documentId: docRef.id }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            status: 200
        };
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur during processing
        console.error(error);
        return {
            body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Failed to store unique URL' }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            status: 500
        };
    }
}
```

I tried to import connectFirestoreEmulator from other sources but none worked for me. Example:

```
// import { connectFirestoreEmulator } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
```

throws another error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found an answer [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/776)

if you are running a NodeJS backend/script, you must set the environement variable `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST`

```
const useEmulator = true;

if (useEmulator){
    process.env['FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST'] = 'localhost:8080';
}

admin.initializeApp({ ... });
```

Thus there's no need to use the function

```
import { connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Zied, you're correct the admin SDK doesn't use the typical `connectFirestoreEmulator` method. Here's the relevant docs link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#admin_sdks